# What is the problem with this video src path inside a component? [REACT]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, path, src

I have the following structure in my src folder. I am triying to use the video from assets/video/blockchain.mp4 in the VideoBackground.js component (inside components/VideoBackground). But it doesn't display anything.

[image]

For that purpose I am using this variable to store the path:

```js
 const videoSource = "../../assets/video/blockchain.mp4";
```

And then I am using that variable in the source tag here:

```js
<video autoPlay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted>
        <source src={videoSource} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

If I edit videoSource variable in order to add a new url to the same video but in a external server it works. But I am not able to do it with the video stored ino my project.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Are you using create react app? If so the video should go in the public folder.

Comment: read this https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/react-tips-working-with-relative-path-using-create-react-app-fe55c5f97a21

Comment: Yes I am using create. But I have img inside the assets folder and them are displaying ok so I thought it will work fine with videos also. I will read the guide. Thank yo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered the solution:

You have to import the video as this:

```js
import videoSource from "./your-path-to-the-video";
```

And then you can use the videoSource value in the source tag of the video as I did in the first post and it works.